# Pypi package : where is my executable?

Tags: linux, pypi, python-3.5

(Archlinux/Python3.5)

I'm working on [a small Python3 project](https://github.com/suizokukan/katal) made up of only [one Python file](https://github.com/suizokukan/katal/blob/master/katal/katal.py) . With the help of tutorials like [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html), I've created [a Pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Katal) with the following commands :

```
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel register -r pypi   (ok, no error msg)
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload -r pypi     (ok, no error msg)
```

... and I thought I would juste have to write :

```
$ sudo pip install katal    (ok, no error msg)
```

and then, e.g. :

```
$ katal --version
```

... in order to use it.

But the last command fails : there's no `katal` or `Katal` command; if I take a look at `/usr/lib/Python3.5/site-packages/` , I only see the following files (no .py file have been installed !) :

```
  /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Katal-0.0.9.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Katal-0.0.9.dist-info/METADATA
  /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Katal-0.0.9.dist-info/RECORD
  /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Katal-0.0.9.dist-info/WHEEL
  /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Katal-0.0.9.dist-info/metadata.json
  /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Katal-0.0.9.dist-info/top_level.txt
```

I've obviously forgotten something... But what ? My [setup.py](https://github.com/suizokukan/katal/blob/master/setup.py) clearly [defines](https://github.com/suizokukan/katal/blob/master/setup.py#L64) where is the unique package of my project (=take everything but the `test` directory, including the `katal` sub-directory) :

```
 packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your setup.py, there is a section which is commented out:

```
...
##entry_points={
##    'console_scripts': [
##        'sample=sample:main',
##    ],
##
...
```

This is where I would normally define an executable, please see [this tutorial](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html). You can also define a `scripts` argument to setup which works a little differently (and might match your use case a little better), but that is covered in the tutorial I linked to.

Comment: thank you for the tip ! I tried with 'console_scripts': 'katal=katal.katal',] but, except setup.py, there's no .py file in the package; specifically, the katal/ subdirectory doesn't appear in the tar ball to be downloaded on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Katal/0.0.9 .

Comment: Same problem with     scripts=[os.path.join(".", "katal", "katal.py")],

Comment: yes, it's strange, I'm looking into this. It seems setuptools fails to find the katal package, so anything passed to `scripts` or `entry_points["console_scripts"]` will be ignored. The real problem is that I cannot see anything wrong with how you use `find_packages` this should work...But I've taken an interest in this so I'm working on it. Will update my answer when I find something.

Comment: OK, so I was able to get it to work by adding `scripts=['katal/katal.py']`. My guess is that the package on pypi is stale and you will need to reversion, add the scripts argument and then upload again. Then you should be able to call `katal.py` from the command line. I would avoid `os.path.join(".", ...)` as this will be executed at install/build time instead of made relative to the directory after install.

Comment: you're right ! My apologize for the flood. Thank you for all the details. I updated my OP.